# How to remove webbing from curved mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

How do I remove the webbing/  starlacc pit from the mesh after subdividing..

[image]

Comment: what's happening and what you want is not clear, perhaps share your file

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5190" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5190/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you've filled the bottom and top edges with a simple *F* (fill), but as the shape is round it goes bad because the center of the whole face is out of this semi-circular shape. So you should keep quads:

- Select those faces and press <kbd>X</kbd> (delete) > *Faces*.
- Now select all these vertices except the extreme right and left ones.
- Press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*. It will fill the gap between the edges.
- Then finish the process, select the extreme right vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd>. Same for the extreme left vertices.
- Do the exact same process for the opposite edge.

[image]