# Webbing when subdividing with creases

Tags: subdivision-surface

In order to create a window-like insert:

- I took a plane and with some edge loops and vertice merging I got the shape of the thing
- I then extruded it to make it three dimensional
- I added crease modifiers to designate which edges should remain sharp
- I then added a subdivision modifier

Now it seems to work properly but there is this strange webbing occurring at the creased corners that i cannot for the life of me figure out how to get rid of. When I made this object the first time I had created a few triangles and Google searches told me that the subdiv modifier does not play nice with triangles so I the converted all triangles to quads but that did not help with the webbing issue.

[image: Webbings]

[I did find this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117526/how-to-remove-webbing-from-curved-mesh) and also [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177422/subdivision-surface-artifact-with-creases) however I do not believe the problems there have the same origin as my issue. Because my creases do not end somewhere amidst my model, all normals are pointing in the right direction, and the faces seem to be properly connected.

How do I get these webbings to go away?

[Blender file download](https://pasteall.org/media/9/0/900e7f8d19b386d9fd390cbc61bb0797.blend)

Comment: Please use the official [pasteall.org](https://pasteall.org/blend/) or [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/help) channels to upload your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple just add an edge loop wherever you find these 'webbed parts' in your mesh. Adding edge loops sharpens the smooth, rounded edges whenever you use the subdivision surface modifier. Just select your mesh, tab into edit mode and press 'Ctrl+R'.

[image]

Please add edge loops in the marked areas

[image]